# Serial Port Endpoint for Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, mina

I wanted to know whether there is any endpoints available for reading from Serial port in Apache Camel. I heard that MINA can be used for the purpose but I can't find an example for that. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Nice question. I'm also interested in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking usb, rather than rs232 the Stream component would do it.
This is what I use to read my arduino on my MacBook:

```
<route>
    <from uri="stream:file?fileName=/dev/cu.usbserial-A900acSz&amp;scanStream=true&amp;scanStreamDelay=1000"/>
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String"/>
<to uri="seda:myfeed"/>
</route>
```

scanStream gives you a tail -f equivalent on a 'file'.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But i need an RS232 endpoint. Anyway this was a usefull info.

Comment: Sadly MINA2 Serial wasn't included in the latest build. There are some code about; see http://osdir.com/ml/users-camel-apache/2014-02/msg00609.html for example. Or you could use a serial->tcp/ip bridge and go that way.